# PHP MySQL data insert not working

Tags: php, mysql

My php script to insert data into a db is not working.  It isn't giving any error messages either, so I do not know what is wrong.  What is wrong?

My table:

```
Number  Name        Type            Null    Default      
1       Timestamp   timestamp       No      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
2       BTC         float           Yes     NULL
3       USD         float           Yes     NULL
```

My script:

```
<?php
$json_url = "https://crypto-trade.com/api/1/ticker/dvc_btc";
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);
$DVCdata = $json_feed->data;
$DVCask = $DVCdata->min_ask;
$json_url1 = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD";
$json_data1 = file_get_contents($json_url1);
$json_feed1 = json_decode($json_data1);
$BTCask = $json_feed1->ask;
$DVC_USD = $BTCask * $DVCask;
$DVCround = round($DVC_USD, 8);
$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.serversfree.com",user,pass,database); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO database (BTC, USD)
VALUES ('$DVCask', '$DVCround')");

mysqli_close($connection);    
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `mysqli_query` returns anything? Have you looked to see if `mysqli_error()` returns anything?

Comment: I'm hoping your `mysqli_connect()` parameters are just dummy variables for the sake of masking the real values? As the syntax is obviously wrong.

Comment: FLOAT? Are you sure?!!?

Comment: Yes, they are in the form of w.xyz

Comment: @JohnConde  How is the syntax incorrect?  I'm new to this so sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`database` is a reserve MySQL keyword. You will need to use backticks on the table name in order to use `database` as a table name.

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `database` (BTC, USD)
VALUES ('$DVCask', '$DVCround')");
```

More info [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)